# How can I recreate "BeReal" function of taking a front and back photos with SwiftUI/UiKIt

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, avfoundation

I'm currently working on a personal project: a To-Do List app. The twist is that I want it to function like the BeReal app, where tasks disappear after 24 hours. The app allows for automatic picture-taking with both the front and back cameras. I've managed to get the front camera to work; the picture it takes fits nicely in the top left corner of the screen. However, I'm facing an issue where the button to choose the taken picture is unresponsive. I know that taking a picture from both cameras simultaneously is possible with AVFoundation but I really don't understand it, pretty new to this framework to be honest. So I tried with if statements when the first picture is taken the back camera activates but I'm stuck at the choose photo after it was taken [FrontCameraWorking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LkBN.png)

**SwiftUI View**

```
import SwiftUI

struct CameraViewOne: View {
    @State private var isImagePickerPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var frontImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var backImage: UIImage? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Display back image
            if let backImage = backImage {
                Image(uiImage: backImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    // Display front image at the top left corner
                    if let frontImage = frontImage {
                        Image(uiImage: frontImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerPresented, content: {
            ImagePicker(isPresented: $isImagePickerPresented, frontImage: $frontImage, backImage: $backImage)
        })
        .onAppear {
            self.isImagePickerPresented = true
        }
    }
}



struct CameraViewOne_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CameraViewOne()
    }
}
```

**Swift File UIKit**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var frontImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var backImage: UIImage?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.cameraDevice = .front
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        var usingFrontCamera = true
        
        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                if usingFrontCamera {
                    parent.frontImage = uiImage
                } else {
                    parent.backImage = uiImage
                }
            }
            
            if usingFrontCamera {
                picker.cameraDevice = .rear
                usingFrontCamera = false
            } else {
                picker.cameraDevice = .front
                usingFrontCamera = true
                parent.isPresented = false
            }
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parent.isPresented = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely have to manage the AV capture session on your own instead of using the easy `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: [Capture frames from both cameras at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769114/capture-frames-from-both-cameras-telephoto-and-wideangle-in-the-same-time) and [Capture video simultaneously from both front and rear camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71656435/4667835) might be helpful. You'll need to create your own `AVCaptureSession`, since `UIImagePickerController` only supports a single camera at a time.